# how to grab the relative path of a file with php

Tags: php, path, relative-path

i am trying to catch the relative path to a file to create a share link.
From my `httpdocs` folder on the webserver, my file is here:

```
jack/single/uploads/folder1/image.jpg
```

The var `$dir . '/' . $file` gives me this output:

```
uploads/folder1/image.jpg
```

`realpath($dir . '/' . $file` gives me this output:

```
/home/vhosts/example.com/subdomains/develop3/httpdocs/jack/single/uploads/folder1/image.jpg
```

What i want to achieve is this output:

```
`http://develop3.example.com/jack/single/uploads/folder1/image.jpg`
```

How can i achieve this, so that i can create a share link?

Comment: What happens if you change the magic variable `$dir` accordingly?

Comment: `jack/single/uploads/folder1 ` ; so only the directory where the file is in

Comment: If `$dir` contains what you've posted, attaching another `/` and another variable will never return a variable that does not contain `jack/single` in the front

Comment: just replace /home/vhosts/example.com/subdomains/develop3/httpdocs with http://develop3.example.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `preg_replace` on the output of `realpath` to replace everything up to `httpdocs` with your site's URL:

```
echo preg_replace('#^' . preg_quote($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '[\\\\/]#', "{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/", realpath('test6.php')) . "\n";
```

Comment: This works fine. I assume, every webserver uses `httpdocs`, so anyone else who uses this script on his webserver gets always the right path to the file?

Comment: @JackMaessen actually a lot don't, so I've edited my answer to make it more robust. Assuming your target file sits under the document root (`httpdocs` on your server) then this will work (even on Windows servers)

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] to get you site's name:

```
function get_link($to_file){
    return "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/jack/single/".$to_file;
}

echo get_link($dir . '/' . $file);
```

Change the function's url parts according to your project (do you use https or http? Will /jack/single always be the parent folder of uploads?)

Comment: I agree, this works. But what if someone else uses this script and puts it in a different folder? Then `jack/single` is not actual anymore. So i need something that checks the relative path from the webserver

Comment: in your project were is the php script? also check the content of $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], it shoud contain that relative path you'r looking for